# How to read all file names in a directory with jenkins active choices parameter?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

How can I read all file names in a directory and display them as a dropdown in Jenkins GUI?

My goal is actually creating two depending dropdowns where a user chooses a file in the first dropdown and regarding the choice, in the second dropdown, the first selected file content will be shown to the user as a parameter.

I've tried the following but without success.

In the Active Choice Parameter - Groovy Script:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("/some/path/to/variable/TEST/*")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}
return list
```

Here Active Choice Parameter Name is `SWITCH`
and

In the Active Choices Reactive Parameter

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def list = []

File textfile= new File("/some/path/to/variable/${SWITCH}") 
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsedJson = slurper.parse(textfile)
parsedJson.each{ list.add(it.port_name + " " + it.description)}
return list
```

PS: Files are JSON formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem so if anyone needs:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("/some/path/to/variable/TEST/")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list.add(file.getName())
}

return list
```

Comment: It would help to add a little bit of text describing the solution, for search engines or screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the option `Referenced parameters` as in the screenshot:
[image]

The description of this filed is [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin):

> This option, takes a list of job parameters that trigger an
> auto-refresh of the Reactive Parameter when any of the 'Referenced
> parameters' change

Update:

For me works with your code, except one small change:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def list = []

File textfile= new File("${SWITCH}")
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsedJson = slurper.parse(textfile)
parsedJson.each {
    list.add "$it.port_name $it.description".toString()
}
return list
```

I added `toString()` for each list element to convert the items of GString type  to String. I assume this was your problem. Without `toString()`, Jenkins displays [Object object] because it does not know how to convert it.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your reply, but I did the exact same thing (an active choices parameter named as SWITCH and active choices reactive parameter referenced parameter is again SWITCH) but it is not working. I assume I'm missing something with groovy scripts.

Comment: Hi, thank you again for your time. I've tried what you've done, and it seems correct to me but, I can't understand why the files in the first part (Active Choices Parameter) are not listed. I don't get anything back; it is just empty. I don't see any syntax error, and it can't be a permission issue because I can access the same path with an extensible choice in the same job. It should first list the file names so that the second part (Active Choices Reactive Parameter) can work.

Comment: Probably it is because of the last `*`. On Windows it works without it e.g. `"C:/temp/"`

Comment: It's a Linux host but I've tried both (with or without a star(*)) and the result is the same.